# htaccess creation through php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Before anything, I except the kind of answers "This is a BIGGGGG security issue", no problem with that however I would like a detailled answer of the risks please.

Here is my problem:
I am using php to automatically secure some folders, without having to edit the files inside. It then goes by .htaccess. The thing is that the .htaccess and .htpasswd files are created, with the good access rights (and so on for the folders) however it always returns a 500 internal error and when I check the error log there is nothing specifically written about the error. If I create the files manually, it works.

Here is the php code:

```
$htpath = '../../.htpasswds/'.$ref;
mkdir($htpath, 0750);               
$htpass = $htpath.'/.htpasswd';
$ourFileHandle = fopen($htpass, 'wb') or die("Can't create .htpasswd file.");
$chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789";
$special_chars = '-_@#)([]|-=';
$pass = $chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)].$special_chars[rand(0,strlen($special_chars)-1)].$chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)].rand(0, 9999).$chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)].$special_chars[rand(0,strlen($special_chars)-1)];
$content = 'client_access'.$id.':'.crypt($pass, base64_encode($pass));
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $content) or die("Can't create .htaccess file.");                
fclose($ourFileHandle);

$htpass = $path.'/.htaccess';
$handle = fopen($htpass, 'wb') or die("Can't create .htpasswd file.");
$content = 'AuthType "Basic" ';
$content .= "\n";
fwrite($handle, $content);              
$content = 'AuthUserFile "/home/thedigi1/.htpasswds/'.$ref.'/.htpasswd" ';
$content .= "\n";               
fwrite($handle, $content);
$content = 'Require valid-user ';
$content .= "\n";               
fwrite($handle, $content);
$content = 'RewriteOptions inherit';
$content .= "\n";               
fwrite($handle, $content) or die("Can't create .htaccess file.");
fclose($handle);
```

Do you have any idea of what may cause the problem? Or maybe a better solution please?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
here is the code of the htaccess created:

```
AuthType "Basic" 
AuthUserFile "/home/thedigi1/.htpasswds/A-161012-47/.htpasswd" 
Require valid-user 
RewriteOptions inherit
```

However I am already authentified through a htaccess to access to the php file which creates the htaccess, do you think it could be the problem?

Comment: Which user/group is running httpd? Under which user/group is .htpasswd .htaccess created? What is the content of the .htaccess file which you created by the script? Can you please post it

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ls -l` of a directory and .htaccess you've created via PHP. I suspect it might be the permission issue with the directory and files you're creating via PHP code.

Comment: I can't do any SSH connection to this shared server if that's what you mean. Permissions of the directories are 750, 644 for the .htaccess. I really think this might be a problem with the user/group. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

htaccess file was missing AuthName argument

```
AuthName "text"
```

And I had to CHMOD the .htpasswd folder to 755 and not 750.

Thanks for your answers!